# Match List of Numbers in For Loop in Bash

Tags: bash, if-statement, curl, awk

I have a script that loops over a `curl` command, which pulls in data from an API.

```
LIST_OF_ID=$(curl -s -X POST -d "username=$USER&password=$PASS&action=action" http://link.to/api.php)

for PHONE_NUMBER in $(echo $LIST_OF_ID | tr '_' ' ' | awk '{print $2}');
do
  $VOIP_ID = $(echo $LIST_OF_ID | tr '_' ' ' | awk '{print $1}')
done
```

I also have a variable of 16 numbers in the range of "**447856321455**"

```
NUMBERS=$(cat << EOF
441111111111
441111111112
441111111113
... etc
)
```

The output on the API call is:

```
652364_441111111112
```

As you may notice I have taken the output and cut it into 2 parts and put it in a variable.

What I need is to match the 6 digit code from the output where the number in the output, matches with the number in the variable.

I've attempted it using `if` statements but I can't work my head around the correct way of doing it.

Any help would be appreciated.

Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

I would do it using `join` rather than a loop in bash.  Like this:

```
curl -s -X POST -d "$PARAMS" "$URL" | sort \
  | join -t _ -2 2 -o 2.1 <(sort numbers.txt) -
```

What this does is take the sorted output from `curl` and join it with the sorted contents of `numbers.txt` (you could use `$NUMBERS` too), using `_` as the separator, using column `2` of file `2` which is `-` meaning stdin (from curl).  Then output field `2.1` which is the six-digit ID.

Answer (score 0):

Read [why-is-using-a-shell-loop-to-process-text-considered-bad-practice](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/169716/why-is-using-a-shell-loop-to-process-text-considered-bad-practice) and then do something like this:

```
curl ... |
awk -v numbers="$NUMBERS" -F'_' '
    BEGIN { split(numbers,tmp,/[[:space:]]+/); for (i in tmp) nums[tmp[i]] }
    $2 in nums
'
```

but to be honest I cant really tell what it is you are trying to do as the numbers in your sample input don't seem to match each other (what does `in the range of "447856321455"` mean and how does it relate to $NUMBERS containing `441111111111` through `441111111113` and how does any of that relate to `match the 6 digit code`) and the expected output is missing.